# convert struct __CFString * to CFStringRef

Tags: core-foundation

How can I convert struct __CFString * to CFStringRef?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`CFStringRef` is a typedef for `struct const __CFString *`, so you can just pass it into your method/function.

Comment: Actually, don't even need to cast. They're the same type, `const`ness aside, so it's an implicit conversion.

Comment: Thanks both of you, but doing that gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS. 
I am being passed this a variable(arg1) of this type:
struct __CFString *mCFRef;
when CFStringRef s = arg1;
Now whenever i try to use s like NSLog it for example, i get EXC BAD ACCESS

Comment: Then it probably isn't a `CFString`. What's the actual code look like where you're getting it from?

Comment: Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396873/what-is-cfstring/5396988#5396988
I don't have the source, just the .h file.

Comment: @user635064: Passing the pointer is not the problem; Wevah's answer (as amended) is correct: A `CFStringRef` *is* a `struct const __CFString *`, so no conversion is necessary because you already have it. The problem is that either arg1 is not a pointer to anything, or it is a pointer to not enough storage, or mCFRef has not been set to a pointer to a CFString object, or something did set mCFRef to a pointer to a CFString object but that object has been released by everything that owned it (and possibly one more—an over-release). If it's the last one, Instruments's Zombies template will help.